# i have getting this error 'from selenium import webdriver ImportError: No module named selenium" even though i have installed selenium module

Tags: python, selenium

i'm using pycharm community edition 2.2 with python 2.7

i have installed selenium web driver through pip install selenium command, but whenever importing (from selenium import web driver) selenium module i'm hitting this error : "from selenium import web driver
ImportError: No module named selenium"

please help me..

Comment: Try to run `pip freeze`. Does selenium show up?

Comment: Have you tried to install it directly through PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it through PyCharm:

`File -> Settings -> Project:your_project -> Project Interpreter -> green '+' -> find 'selenium' -> install`