# Troubleshooting installing Selenium WebDriver (macOS High Sierra)?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to use the Selenium WebDriver in a Python 3.5, macOS High Sierra, and Firefox environment. I have not succeeded in installing it. I hence have a question that is related (or even duplicates) questions such as this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597058/i-have-getting-this-error-from-selenium-import-webdriver-importerror-no-module) and this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998084/how-to-install-selenium-python-on-mac). Nontheless, I can't make it work.

Her is what I have done so far:

1. I installed `selenium` via `pip install selenium`. `pip freeze` shows that I installed `selenium==3.9.0`
2. I downloaded the gecko driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
3. I unpacked the package and draged the driver to `/usr/local/bin`. I tried to put it into `/usr/bin` but I can't.
4. I extanded `$PATH`. `echo $PATH` yields `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/JohnDoe/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

When I run `from selenium import webdriver` I am thrown the following error

```
/Users/JohnDoe/anaconda/lib/python3.5/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py in <module> 
No module named 'selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver'
```

Can anybody help?

**Edit:** This question has been marked as a possible duplicate to the question asked here: [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium). However, I get the depicted error when running `from selenium import webdriver`, altough I followed all the steps described.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It's a very neat answer, but somehow doesn't solve my issue. I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Apparently, I had some depency issues. I uninstalled selenium, updaten anaconda, and reinstalled selenium again. Works like a charm now!